# How can I multiply each band of multiband image by separate scalars using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have an image with 5 bands.
I need to multiply each band of this image by different scalars one time
(I'm lazy to do it one by one) and then get multiband image as a output.

For example (band1*1.1) (band*1.2) (band3*1.25) etc.
Then output return to an image with 5 bands.

How can I multiple each band of multiband image by separate scalars at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry for basic question. where can I find this raster calculator tool in arcgis 9.2.

Comment: Check out the following link: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=The_Raster_Calculator.  Or this link: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_Raster_Calculator